# Is the Microsoft Store part of Xbox Live?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was buying Minecraft Windows 10 edition from Gamivo. When I came across it Gamivo said the platform was Xbox Live but above it said it was a Windows 10 product. That really confused me. This is furthered backed by another time I saw a Xbox giftcard and on it said it is usable on the Microsoft Store. So:

1. Can all Xbox things be used on Microsoft Store?
2. If I do buy Minecraft will actually work on Windows 10?
3. If all Xbox things don't work on Microsoft Store which things do?

Link to the game: https://www.gamivo.com/product/minecraft-starter-collection-pc-xbox-one?rp=

Answer (score 2):

> Can all Xbox things be used on Microsoft Store?

Not ***all*** items on Xbox can be used on MS Store.

> If I do buy Minecraft, will it actually work on Windows 10?

Buying Minecraft gives you the real version.

> If all Xbox things don't work on Microsoft Store, which things do?

This is something I can't really answer, but ***maybe*** that gift card you mentioned *could* work.

Comment: No where does it say or imply he pirated it

Comment: what do you mean I pirated it? @Penguin

Comment: @Soumil30 no Mark Giraffe was saying you probably pirated it, I was saying there's no reason to think that. I do believe you bought the game legit

Answer (score -1):

Minecraft is owned by microsoft, although xbox does support it, and minecraft bedrock accounts are made using xbox accounts. So, no you cannot use xbox stuff on the microsoft store, and yes minecraft will work if you buy it.

If you have any further questions feel free to ask me!

Comment: So the game I linked will work on windows 10? Also what about it saying the platform was Xbox live instead of Microsoft Store Xbox gift cards working the MS store?

Comment: I think it will work, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score -1):

The Microsoft store is not part of Xbox live since the Microsoft store is also on windows.

Comment: However licenses do transfer between the two though. (ie. if you subscribe to Game Pass (Ultimate, for the sake of this example) via Xbox or the MS Store, they'll work regardless of which you're using. If you buy a game on the MS Store that includes an Xbox version, it'll come up as owned in the Xbox Store).